# Why isn't $\mathbb{A}^2-x$ an affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

I'm working through Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry,* and one of the exercises asks the reader to prove that $X=\mathbb{A}^2-x,$ where $x$ is a point of $\mathbb{A}^2,$ is not an affine or projective variety. I was able to (convincingly) prove that it is not projective, but the proof that it isn't affine has bothered me. The proof goes by showing that the natural embedding $i$ of $X$ into $\mathbb{A}^2$ would correspond to an isomorphism of coordinate rings, which would imply that $i$ itself is an isomorphism, even though it's not even surjective. Although I understand the logic of the proof, it feels a little bit strange.

I think the issue is that there is some property of $X$ that a projective variety shouldn't have, namely that there are regular functions on it, but I can't think of any property of $X$ that an affine variety shouldn't have. I want to say that the issue is that it is dense in affine space, and a "real" variety shouldn't be, but $V(xy-1)$ can be mapped onto $\mathbb{A}^1-{0},$ contradicting my claim.

Therefore, what is wrong with $X?$ Why can't it be an affine variety? To be clear, I'm not asking for a proof that it isn't, but rather some underlying reason or property making it impossible to be so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any affine variety and any ideal of the coordinate ring not containing $1$, the vanishing set of that ideal is nonempty by the nullstellensatz. But the ideal of the point $x$ in $k[X]=k[\Bbb A^2]$ does not contain 1 but has an empty vanishing set (since we removed $x$).

Comment: Nicely put. Is that actually a characterization of affine varieties? So is a variety $X$ affine if and only if the maximal ideals of $k[X]$ are in bijection with the closed points?

Comment: @red_trumpet that's a good question and I'm not immediately sure. (Maybe I should be!)

Comment: @red_trumpet I think the answer is yes: If a subset $[X]$ of an affine space has a bijection between its points and maximal ideals of $k[X]$, then it is a variety, because coordinate rings themselves correspond to varieties, and we can then map each point of $X$ to the point of the affine variety $V$ corresponding to the same ideal of $k[X].$ I am however just learning algebraic geometry, so I could be making a serious oversight.

Comment: @littleman I don't think I follow you here. An abstract variety $X$ need not be a subset of affine space.

Comment: Thinking a bit more, one always has a morphism $X \to \operatorname{Spec} k[X]$, which is supposed to be a bijection. Of course a bijection of varieties need not be an isomorphism (e.g. the normalization of a cuspidal curve). What I don't see right now is if this bijection is necessarily a homeomorphism?

Comment: @red_trumpet It seems like you're using schemes, which I haven't yet learned about, but the argument I came up with is that the mapping of rings corresponding to the bijection constructed is an isomorphism, being the identity function, so the equivalence of finitely generated reduced $k$-algebras and affine varieties "should" make it a homeomorphism. However, now that I'm thinking about it, if we don't know before hand that $X$ is a variety, I don't know what topology it'd have on it.

Comment: The correct theoretical framework for this is that for any variety $X$, there's an automatic morphism from $X$ to the affine variety with the same coordinate ring (in scheme language, this is the affinization map $X\to\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_X(X)$). The question then is "if this map is bijective, must it be an isomorphism?".